# Can we access data from Dialogflow Agent using API key?

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, https, dialogflow-es

I am trying to integrate the dialog flow agent with a middleware bot. However, due to some issue, I am not able to use service account keys and have to find some alternate method for communication of APIs, Can we use API keys for this purpose?

Comment: Why couldn't you use the Service Account keys ? Have you checked [this tutorial](https://beyondco.de/course/build-a-chatbot/natural-language-processing/using-the-dialogflow-middleware)?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use a solution such as [Cloud Endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi) or [API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs) (which is a Cloud Endpoint fully managed, same configuration, same features for now).

I wrote an article on [Coud Endpoint with ESPv2 on Cloud Run](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1)